# How i make android menu work for tables and phones?

Tags: android, menu

I create an android application with menu(About,Setup,Exit) work fine with my smartphone but not work with Tablets.How i fix it?This is my code...work for smartphones...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
  MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
  menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
  return true;
}

 @Override 
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {

  switch (item.getItemId())
  {
  case R.id.menu_exit:

      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
       // wl.release();

      finish();
      return true;

  case R.id.menu_about:

      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
       // wl.release();

      startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
      return true;    

  case R.id.menu_sos:

      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        //wl.release();

      startActivity(new Intent(this, sos.class));
      return true;

  case R.id.menu_map:

      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        //wl.release();
      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarineNavigator.class); //Send current location to map
     i.putExtra("latcur",lat);
     i.putExtra("lngcur",lng);
     startActivity(i);

      return true;        

  case R.id.menu_setup_map: 

      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        //wl.release();

      startActivity(new Intent(this, Setup2.class));
      return true;            


  default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

I test this...for tablets and work....but no display anything icons or inflate anything just go to next activity...How i modify this to work for me?Some add code?Example?Thanks.

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              //Default generate when we make app on Eclipse...
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.marine_navigator, menu);

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarineNavigator.class); //Send current location to map
     i.putExtra("latcur",lat);
     i.putExtra("lngcur",lng);
     startActivity(i);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem that u r facing?...can u explain?

Comment: How i can modify the second to work?Need someone to tell me with code...

Comment: Same code will work on tablets and phones (assuming the OS version is sufficient). Check this guide out: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: "Tablets" is a very broad category of devices, and you have not provided enough information for us to help you. I'm guessing you haven't tried it on all tablets, so which ones have you tested with? Which versions of Android are they running? What version are you targeting?

Comment: Android Sony Xperia smartphone test it OS 4.0 and tablet Samsung OS 3.0.My apk minVersion 7.